# Reuse CSS style and apply to other HTML element

Tags: html, css

I would like to reuse given css formatting `.parsley-errors-list > li` and apply it to different HTML element than it it designed to be used for. I would like to apply it to `<span>` in order not to create another duplicated style and to be sure that `span` will always be of the same style as `.parsley-errors-list > li`.

```
.parsley-errors-list {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.parsley-errors-list > li {
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: none;
    color: #f05050;
}
```

EDIT:

Given CSS sample is part of an updatable theme, so I would like to avoid changing it for the maintainability.

Comment: `.parsley-errors-list > li, span`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's very easy to do. Just put a comma on the CSS selector like this:

```
.parsley-errors-list > li, span {
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: none;
    color: #f05050;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however this will apply to all `span` elements. And secondly requires me to modify CSS file, which is part of an updatable theme, so I would like to avoid changing it for maintainability. Is there any other way to reuse `.parsley-errors-list` for `span`?

Comment: @Megrez7 You will need to modify css file no matter what. You basically list the rule selectors separated by comma so the same styles apply to all of your selectors